# How to construct SAS Macro variables with single quotes

Tags: sas

I have a macro variable:

```
%let names = name1, name2, name3, name4
```

The real variable can vary in length. What I want to do is make a new variable datalist, which looks like this:

```
‘name1’,‘name2’,‘name3’,‘name4’
```

I have tried to make this variable in the following way:

```
%str(%’)%sysfunc(tranwrd(%quote(&names.),%str(,),%str(%’ ,%’)))%str(%’))
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release. Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended.
```

Adding white spaces does not help though. Does anyone know a different method to construct my desired macro variable?

PS: I have seen the following question, but in that one there were no commas separating the elements in the list. [SAS macro variable quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426109/sas-macro-variable-quotes)

Comment: Modify the SQL that creates the list of names.  use quote(strip(var),"'")

Comment: What is the problem you are having adapting the code in the question you linked to your existing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same method used before, but take care to hide the commas in NAMES from %SYSFUNC().

```
%let names = name1, name2, name3, name4 ;
%let qnames = %sysfunc(tranwrd(%bquote('&names'),%str(, ),', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
38         proc sql noprint;
39            select quote(strip(name),"'") into :namelist separated by ', ' from sashelp.class;
40            quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
      

41         
42         %put NOTE: &=namelist;
NOTE: NAMELIST='Alice', 'Barbara', 'Carol', 'Jane', 'Janet', 'Joyce', 'Judy', 'Louise', 'Mary', 'Alfred', 'Henry', 'James', 
'Jeffrey', 'John', 'Philip', 'Robert', 'Ronald', 'Thomas', 'William'
```

Comment: Probably better to use TRIM() instead of STRIP().  If any of the values have leading spaces STRIP() will remove them which will result in quoted strings that will not match the values in the original variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the other approaches to work.  This abomination did:

```
%global quoted_list;
%let request_status = item1+item2+item3;

%macro parselist(s);
  data work.tmplist;
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&s,"+"));
      %let word = %scan(&s,&i,"+");
      x="&word";
      output;
    %end;
  run;

  proc sql NOprint;
    select quote(trim(x),"'") into :quoted_list separated by ', ' from tmplist;
  quit;
%mend;

%macro main();
  %if "X&request_status." ne "X" %then %do;
    %parselist(&request_status.);
    %put &quoted_list;
  %end;
%mend;
%main;
```